# Can i replace the getter function in the constructor (with super for example) and how?

Tags: java, oop

What is the better way of creating an object of a sub class without using getter function as a parameter in its constructor?

I've done it with getter functions

```
/*constructor(subclass)*/
public HourlyEmployee(String name, int age, String SSN,int hoursWorked,double hourlyWages)
{
    super(name,age,SSN);
    this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
    this.hourlyWages = hourlyWages; 
}

/*main*/
public class Run
{
    public static void main(String[] arggs)
    {
        Employee e = new Employee("ABC", 50, "XYZ7009205");
        HourlyEmployee h = new HourlyEmployee(e.getName(), e.getAge(), e.getSSN(), 5, 10.0);

        System.out.println(h);  
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean: replace getter with super?

Comment: How about a constructor like `HourlyEmployee(Employee base, int hoursWorked,double hourlyWages) ` and then calling the "copy" constructor `Employee(Employee copy)` (which you'd have to add) via `super(base)`?

Comment: Can't you overload a constructor with an Employee object as an argument instead if individual fields?

Comment: Hi @user617463, help us help you : what is you overall goal? Is HourlyEmployee supposed to be a sub-class of Employee? If so you may be confused. Tell us what you want to achieve, and maybe include some more code !

Comment: Highbrainer, thanks for your time. Yes it is a sub-class of  Employee. In main while creating an object of sub-class  HourlyEmployee I'm passing getter function(e.getName) as a parameter because of name's private access. Now can I do it without using getter function?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use **Inheritance** and write HourlyEmployee as:

```
public class HourlyEmployee extends Employee {

    public HourlyEmployee(String name, int age, String SSN, int hoursWorked, double horlyWages) {
        super(name,age,SSN);
        this.hoursWorked=hoursWorked;
        this.hourlyWages=hourlyWages; 
    }

}
```

or you can use Decorator Pattern as:

```
public class HourlyEmployee {

    public HourlyEmployee(Employee employee, int hoursWorked, double horlyWages) {
        this.employee = employee;
        this.hoursWorked=hoursWorked;
        this.hourlyWages=hourlyWages; 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
Employee e = new HourlyEmployee("ABC", 50, "XYZ7009205", 5, 10.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Joop Eggen answer, when you call the subclass, you don't have to worry about the main class of that subclass because you already implement the methods of that main class in your subclass. Thus, calling subclass will also include the main class methods. **So it's going to be:**

```
 Employee e = new Employee("ABC", 50, "XYZ7009205", 5, 10.0);

 System.out.println(e);
```